# Set rounded color background to text in TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, textfield, paint

I would like my text background in Textfield looks like this :

[image]

But with this code :

```
     style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue
                ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
```

I have this result :

[image]

There is no **padding**, no **rounded corners** and a **transparent line** between both...

How can I do this ?

EDIT :

Another way with `TextStyle` was provided by @Csaba Mihaly but this is a workaround I want to avoid. I'm looking for a custom paint solution

EDIT :

According answers provided PaintStyle.stroke can be used but it's not 100% matching the expected result (first screen) :

No matter the text size is, in order to fill the empty space the stroke width must be bigger as I can see. It will render a large padding and corner radius. In my case :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't qualify as an answer but a definite improvement: https://dartpad.dev/?258cf448c698d3e9888d6a7bb0862839&null_safety=true

I believe the solution would involve CustomPainter because of the merging effect of the bubbles.

Comment: @happy_san  could you provide an answer ?

Comment: I'll post if I get an answer.

Comment: Someone already asked for this before
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354364/how-to-make-custon-editable-textbox-on-a-canvas-in-flutter-in-which-background-s

Comment: Do you want to modify your provided TextStyle to drive to your or want to try a different approach to get same result?

Comment: @Diwyansh try a different approach is ok but I think the best solution is to create a custom paint with the TextStyle. just don't know how.  Answers below use PaintStyle stroke as I found but it's not working with a large text fontsize because it will be transparent inside. The more the fontsize is bigger the more the stroke width should be. And then it will be not the same result (too large rounded corner and padding)

Answer (score 8):

You code snippet will work if you add `..strokeWidth = 20` to the style, e.g.:

```
Text(
    'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. ',
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
     background: Paint()
       ..color = Colors.blue
       ..strokeWidth = 20
       ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
       ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
       ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
     color: Colors.white,
    ))
```

[image]

Stroke width defines the 'fatness' of the area around the text. Though to be accurate, the inside corners (look near word 'industry') are not rounded, I doubt text background can fix that.

Also please not that if you're targeting Web you might need to use Skia renderer instead of HTML renderer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/69975665/440696) in order to avoid the following artefact:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please see edits

Answer (score 4):

I created a package called `rounded_background_text` to achive this

https://pub.dev/packages/rounded_background_text

[image: Showcase]

Usage:

```dart
import 'package:rounded_background_text/rounded_background_text.dart';

RoundedBackgroundText(
  'A cool text to be highlighted',
  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
),
```

TextFields are also supported

Answer (score 3):

Just give the desired `strokeWidth` value and it will work fine.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKW45.png)

```
style: TextStyle(
        background: Paint()
          ..strokeWidth = 17
          ..color = Colors.blue
          ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,

        color: Colors.black,
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please see edits

Comment: It doesn't work on web with the html renderer

Answer (score 2):

So I found this article https://medium.com/@pinkesh.earth/flutter-quick-tip-how-to-set-text-background-color-with-curve-d40a2f96a415
It describes how to use textstyle to look like what you want, but it doesn't exactly work like that, I don't know why. It draws the next line's background above the previous.

I managed to work around it (bug?) by stacking two textfields(one has transparent text, the other transparent background).

The result:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final myControllerName = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          fillColor: Colors.transparent,
          filled: true,
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
        )),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Stack(
          children: [
            IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                controller: myControllerName,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    background: Paint()
                      ..strokeWidth = 25
                      ..color = Colors.blue
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            IntrinsicWidth(
              child: TextField(
                controller: myControllerName,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . this is exactly what I found days ago before I put the bounty. and I wrapped the first textfield by AbsorbPointer to avoid conflicts. I am sorry I can't accept this workaround because I'm looking for a custom paint solution . I'm going to edit my question according your solution .

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue
                ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
                ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                ..strokeWidth = 30.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please see edits

Answer (score 1):

You can use a container. Try this:

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Hello World!',
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(<value>),
      ),
```

You can find other examples here https://stacksecrets.com/flutter/flutter-textfield-decoration-in-depth#How_To_Decorate_Border_Of_TextField

Comment: Try with specifying the keyboardType property

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be done with this . Please see my screenshot